# Check Client's integrity

Tags: java, android, security

I'm developing an Android App on an open protocol.

It'll be open source but I want the server (closed source) to be able to check whether the client is the original app or a modification ( compiled by someone else ).

Is that possible on Android?

Comment: You cannot tell the difference between network bytes from your app and network bytes from a hostile party.  Period.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is impossible to prove the absence of modified code, and the presence of unmodified code doesn't mean that that unmodified code is the only code.

Imagine that your open source application has code to prove its authenticity in *any* manner. Any modification can simply keep, carry over, or copy this authenticity information. 
If the authenticity information actually checks the program's code or data itself, it is still possible for the adversary to use the code/data of a good program and impersonate it.

Answer (score 0):

You could secure the server side with SSL and require a client side certificate.  When you distribute the source code, do not distribute the certificate that the code is using to communicate with the server.  Modified versions of the app would then have to create their own certificate to communicate with the server and the server could determine what certificate was used to establish the SSL connection.

Comment: No; attackers can extract the cert from the original client.

Comment: @SLaks Yeah.  If someone wanted to I suppose they could pull it from the apk.

Comment: and what about putting it in a native (NDK) part of the app

Comment: @user3233251: If your app can read the cert, an attacker can also read the cert.  It is fundamentally impossible to do something on a device without letting the device do it.